# Why is this wrong? UnboundLocalError: local variable 'xxx' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, global-variables

I tried to put this code into a function in order to apply with .apply in a pandas df. But it yield the error mentioned:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ru_blade' referenced before assignment
```

Unless I am missing something else, this doesn't make sense since I don't have duplicate global variables.

Here is the code.

```
    def parent_chassis(df):
    
    for index, row in df.iterrows():

        if row['Type'] == 'Blade Server':
            ru_chassis = row['RU']
            parent = row['Name']
            #print(ru_chassis, parent)
        if row['Type'] == 'Server Blade':
            ru_blade = row['RU']
            #print(ru_blade)
        if ru_blade == ru_chassis and row['Type'] == 'Server Blade':
            parent_chassis = parent
                #print(parent_chassis)
        return parent_chassis

     parent_chassis(rackwise_chassis_blade):
```

Comment: if `if row['Type'] == 'Server Blade'` is FALSE, then `ru_blade ` is NOT defined

Answer (score 1):

If your code didn't enter in second `if`, `ru_blade` didn't define and then in third `if` you used that and got error.